# Tangential Vector

Tags: differential-geometry

I have trouble to understand the following definition.

> If $M$ is a differentiate manifold then the tangent vector in $p\in M$ is a map $v:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $v(f)=0$ if $f$ stationary and $v$ is linear.
>   $\mathcal{F}=\{f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R},$ $U$ open neighbourhood of $p$, $f$ differentiable$\}$

What should I understand under the condition that $v(f)$ is zero for such a function?

Comment: I think the definition you have written is not correct.

Comment: It has to be correct :D what do u think that is wrong?

Comment: Yes. For this definition, you need that $v$ is a linear map ($v(af+bg)=a v(f) + b v(g)$ for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $f,g\in\mathcal{F}$) and that it is a derivation ($v(fg) = f(p)v(g)+v(f)g(p)$ for all $f,g\in\mathcal{F}$). I don't think you can derive the derivation condition from the requirement that $v(f)=0$ for constant functions.

Comment: With stationary is meant that the map $D(fo\phi ^{-1} )(\phi (p))=0$ where $\phi$ is a chart. Do we mean the same thing?